# Can Map count occurrences more than once?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I read in a tutorial that `Map` counts every word in a dictionary like this:
`('house', 1)`.

Then in a huge text it may find the word 'house' many times. Hence, the `Reduce` function will take as many (house,1) exist from the `Map` function and it will iterate giving a `('house',100)` if it found it 100 times in a document.

Is this how it works? Why the second time the `Map` function finds the word 'house' doesn't store it `('house',2)`?

Answer (score 0):

The Mapper is called on every item in your input and then it emits a series of intermediate key/value pairs.

Those key/value pairs look like this: **(feature, partial aggregate value)** or **(house, 1)** in your example. After, all the emitted values for a given key are grouped together likes this **(feature, (value1, value2, etc.)** or **(house, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1))**.

In the end, the Reducer computes the final aggregate result from all the intermediate values for that feature. So, **(feature, (value1, value2, etc.)** becomes **(feature, totalValue)**. Or **(house, (1, 1, 1, 1, 1))** becomes **(house, 5)**.

The Mapper does not count how many times that feature (or word in your example) occurs, it simply splits the output as (feature, value). It is the job of the Reducer to compute the final aggregate for the feature. Otherwise, what would be the purpose of the Reducer?

*I need to specify that I am currently learning about Hadoop and the MapReduce programming model. Thus, if I am wrong, correct me.*

Comment: There's one mapper per *input split*, not item (for example line in a file). And a mapper doesn't have to immediately output a "partial aggregate". It is up to the developer to implement whatever logic makes sense; maybe the word is converted to characters, then 5 results would be emitted for `house`, or certain words are filtered out (called stop words in text processing), or stemmed, etc

Comment: @cricket_007 I've said on every item IN THE input. That item is a line, word or whatever you want to find/count. The input data is then partitioned into processable chunks and one Map job is executed per chunk. I also adapted my answer to his question.

Comment: The map function is called on each Record of the InputSplit, sure, but given there's a small file, it's only one mapper instance in total. That's all I was clarifying